# How to boot Windows from Clover UEFI shell

Tags: windows-10, boot, grub, uefi, bootloader

How to boot Windows from Clover UEFI shell.

I don't have access to anything but it. When I normally boot it gives

```
error : unknown file system
entering rescue mode
grub rescue>_
```

May be that's because, I deleted a Linux partition.

I had an USB with Clover on it. Now I can access the HDD with the Clover shell. Clover is not showing any boot entries.

Is there any way to boot Windows through it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have installed Windows in UEFI mode, you can call Windows Boot Manager directly typing `FS0:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi` <kbd>Enter</kbd> into the EFI shell.  If this isn't found try `FS0:\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI` (case doesn't matter).

If you don't find either on volume `FS0:` then you can try looking for it on other filesystems until you find the one which contains the EFI partition with Windows Boot Manager.

Volumes are in the format `FS0:`,  `FS1:`, `FS2:`, `FS3:` etc.  As the commands `cd` and `ls` work in EFI shell (see [EFI SHELL COMMANDS - quick reference](http://www.sysadminshare.com/2012/01/efi-shell-commands.html)) to see what is on a volume type:

- `FS1:` <kbd>Enter</kbd> do change to volume FS1: (note the `:`)
- `ls` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to list files and directories in root of the filesystem
- `cd EFI`  <kbd>Enter</kbd> to change to directory `EFI`
- `ls` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to list files and directories in `EFI` directory

When you find your bootloader you run it by just typing the name (including the `.efi` suffix) into the shell prompt.

---

If you have legacy BIOS installation then Clover will not boot it.  You could download [rEFInd-flashdrive](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/0.12.0/) an put this on a USB key as described in its [documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html).  If you then boot that it should be able to automatically detect and boot legacy Windows installations.

Comment: FS0:\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI seems to have worked. But after I press enter it returns to the clover main menu. And when I press enter again the screen goes black.

Comment: I mean the first command returned 'is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program, or script file' but the second one didn't show any such error. but it returned back to main menu. Then the screen goes black after I press enter again.

Comment: https://m.imgur.com/a/zJYOeJr. That's a link to a video showing what's happening.

Comment: From your video it looks like `FS0:\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI` is loading clover boot loader.  Can you check with `FS0:` `cd EFI` `ls` if there is a "Microsoft" directory and if so what is in it.

Comment: No, there is no 'Microsoft' directory in FS0:\EFI. There are just 'BOOT' and 'CLOVER' Directories in it. Here's the link to the photo https://imgur.com/a/pLxUDSS

Comment: @MrVajid: Then FS0: is your USB stick, and you probably should be looking at FS1: or FS2: instead?

Comment: @user1686 I checked all volumes and found winload.efi in FS4. But when I run it, it give "Command error status: unsupported" Here's a pic https://imgur.com/a/QWn5Sd1 and maybe that's because I have windows 10 installed on legacy BIOS.

Comment: @MrVajid - Clover will not boot legacy BIOS.  You could try downloading rEFInd - see updated answer.

Comment: @lx07 Thanks for the update. And is there any way to flash it to my android phone without rooting it and use it as a usb. (Because i don't have a mobile to pendrive OTG and can't get it now due to lockdown. And rooting redmi phones without PC is near impossible)